# How to join multiple 'expr' using 'for' and 'count'

Tags: php

Hello all I am trying to find a solution for joining multiple 'expr' together using for with 'count'.Whatever combination I use does not work.

Currently I have:

```
for($i=0; $i<14; $i++) {

//echo some values for the table;

}

//echo a table;

}
```

This sets the amount of values to be used in my tables.

But I have a two breaks where the numbers are missing so I need something like:

e.g 1:

```
//this gives syntax error
for($i=0; $i<2; $i=4; $i<8; $i=10; $i<15; $i++) {

//echo some values for the table;

}

//echo a table;

}
```

e.g 2:

```
//just doesnt work
for($i=0; $i<2; $i++) for($i=4; $i<8; $i++) for($i=10; $i<15; $i++)  {

//echo some values for the table;

}

//echo a table;

}
```

e.g 3:

```
//breaks my table
for($i=0; $i<2; $i++);
for($i=4; $i<8; $i++);
for($i=10; $i<15; $i++)  {

//echo some values for the table;

}

//echo a table;

}
```

e.g 4:

```
//this one is straight out of the php manual & doesnt work
for($i=0; $i<2; $i++)  {
for($i=4; $i<8; $i++)  {
for($i=10; $i<15; $i++)  {

//echo some values for the table;

}
}
}
}

//echo a table;

}
```

Please can you help me I need to find a solution to this - many thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I really dont know how to be any clearer other than number 3 & 9 are missing from the query results so if the count is from 0 to 15 then it affects the table layout and all the results are off by two rows so I need to use multiple counts ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the numbers you expect by forming an array of them with [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge) and [`range()`](http://php.net/range):

```
// $i=0; $i<2; $i=4; $i<8; $i=10; $i<15
foreach( array_merge( range( 0, 2), range( 4, 8), range( 10, 15)) as $i) {
    echo $i;
}
```

**[Output:](http://3v4l.org/FL7FZ)**

```
0 1 2 4 5 6 7 8 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

An alternative approach, you can form the range from `0 - 15`, then remove `3` and `9` and iterate (Here the values we are interested in are in the key of the array, and not the value):

```
$arr = array_flip(range( 0, 15));
unset($arr[3]);
unset($arr[9]);
foreach( $arr as $i => $garbage) {
    echo $i . "\n";
}
```

It produces the same output as above.

Comment: This doesnt work as such I dont think range is the answer in this case. Need to count from 0 to 15 (excluding 3,9) surely there must be a way? if not then only option is to add dummy entries in the data base so the table will have 'unknown' entries.

Comment: @Renny - Try again. Now that I understand your problem a bit more, my edited answer iterates from 0 - 15, skipping 3 and 9.

Comment: lovely thanks a bunch it works great, I put it straight into my code and it seems to have solved the issue :)

Comment: Nick you seem to be on the ball mate, Ive been making modules to query all the battlefield player stats thats (bf3 & 4) now because ea just killed off the others (bf2 & bf2142) which I had completed..typical. I do have one more issue but its flipping hard to explain so when I get round to it I hope you can help :)